# Continuous function space separablity

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

We know that $C[0, \infty)$ is complete metric space with sup norm. 
Is it also seperable? How to show it?

Thank you.

Comment: I assume $C[0,\infty)$ here means the *bounded* continuous functions on $[0,\infty)$; otherwise the sup norm can be infinite.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254626/the-space-of-bounded-continuous-functions-are-not-separable/254652) is a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $f_n$ were countable and dense, how can you make a function that stays away from $f_n(n)$?

Answer (score 1):

A common way to show a normed space is not separable is to present an uncountable set $E$ such that any two distinct elements of $E$ are at distance 1 from each other.  This means that the uncountably many open balls $\{B(x,1/2) : x \in E\}$ are pairwise disjoint.  But each one must contain an element of any dense set, so any dense set must be uncountable.

For the problem at hand, hint: there are uncountably many subsets of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @julien: Thanks, fixed.