# Separability of $C^2_b(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, uniform-convergence, approximation-theory, separable-spaces, weierstrass-approximation

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb R$ be open and bounded. Denote by $C_b^2(\Omega)$ the space of functions $f:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that $f, f', f''\in C_b(\Omega)$. Endow this space with the norm 
$$\|f\|_{C^2_b}:=\|f\|_\infty + \|f'\|_\infty + \|f''\|_\infty.$$
Is the space $(C_b^2(\Omega), \|\cdot\|_{C^2_b})$ separable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For example take the family $\{ \sin(\alpha x) \}_{\alpha\in \mathrm{R}}$. Because $C_b(\Omega)$ is not separable, it admits a family $\{f_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in\mathrm{R}}$ such that $\|f_\alpha-f_\beta\|\geq 1$ for all $\alpha\neq \beta$ (upon renormalizing it). Let $A= \inf \Omega$ and $B=\sup \Omega$ and define
$$ g_\alpha(x) = \int_A^x \int_A^y f_\alpha(z)dz dy, $$
where $f_\alpha$ are extended to $0$ on $(A,B)\setminus \Omega$. It is easy to see that $g_\alpha \in C_b^2(\Omega)$ and that
$$ \|g_\alpha-g_\beta\|_{C^2} \geq \|f_\alpha-f_\beta\|_C \geq 1. $$

If you want a general result on the non-separability of $C_b(\Omega)$, you can check
[this post.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254626/the-space-of-bounded-continuous-functions-are-not-separable)

On the other side, if you ask that the family has derivatives continuous up to $\partial \Omega$, then you have separability. Indeed you can consider the injection
$$ T:C^2(\overline{\Omega})\to C(\overline{\Omega})^3, f\mapsto [f,f',f'']. $$
Then the range of $T$ is a closed subset of the separable metric space $C(\overline{\Omega})^3$, and so separable.

Notice that $C(\overline{\Omega})$ is the [Hausdorff compactification](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Hausdorff_compactifications.html?id=GVfvAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y) of the family
$$ \{f\in C(\Omega): f\text{ is uniformly continuous}\} \subset C_b(\Omega), $$
so you can similarly construct space $\tilde{\Omega}$ by considering certain separable sub-families of $C_b(\Omega)$ (or $C_b^2(\Omega)$) and obtain
$$ C(\tilde{\Omega}) \text{ separable subspace of } C_b(\Omega). $$